# How to locate and size objects relatively on the screen in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I want users to be able to locate objects ,say rectangles, freely on the screen. Each Rectangle will have width, height, x, y.

I want that when users resize browser window, the rectangles change location and size relative to the window while maintaining proportion.

I noticed I could do something width="20%" height="20%" and then object will resize but if the aspect ration is diffenent the rectangles will look distorted. Also I wasn't sure what's the best way to locate object relatively as I noticed I couldn't bind Flexglobals.toplevelapplication.width/Flexglobals.toplevelapplication.height to x/y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to override updateDisplayList() and resize your retangles in that.  UpdateDisplayList() will give you the height and width of the container which you can use to recalculate size and position of the rectangles.

You may benefit from reading up on the [Flex Component LifeCycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html).

Comment: Where do I put the updateDisplayList()? and is it for the whole application or for the Rectangle? a code sample/pseudo code is greatly appreciated

Comment: Every Flex Component has an updateDisplayList() method.  So, you need to override the updateDisplayList() method in whatever container component that contains your rectangles.  I didn't think that Rectangle was a Flex Component, so it probably won't have an updateDisplayList.  Without a code review, I can't say where you need to override updateDisplayList().